# Failed to load magic database at '' Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

```
$rules = array('title' => 'required', 'thumbnail' => 'image|size:500');
$inputs = array('title' => $this->title, 'thumbnail' => $this->thumbnail,);
$validator = Validator::make($inputs, $rules);

if ($validator->fails()) {

}
```

If I remove the `'thumbnail'` it's working, but if it's there, it crashes when it does the `$validator->fails()`

Comment: It "crashes"? Can you be more specific?

Comment: finfo::finfo() [<a href='finfo.finfo'>finfo.finfo</a>]: Failed to load magic database at ''.

This is what I get.

Answer (score 1):

The `Failed to load magic database` message is a PHP error message, not related to Laravel.

There's a problem with your libmagic installation, or it is not installed at all.

http://php.net/manual/en/ref.fileinfo.php

```
PHP Warning:  finfo::finfo(): Failed to load magic database at '/etc/magic' 
PHP Warning:  finfo::file(): The invalid fileinfo object 

These errors can be rectified by copying your magic database (depending on your distro, this file can be anywhere, on debian it's in /usr/share/file/magic) to /etc/magic.mime 

libmagic automatically appends the .mime to the end of the filename, so PHP incorrectly reports the path it was looking for. 

The same applies for: 
PHP Warning:  finfo::finfo(): Failed to load magic database at '/etc/magic.mime' 

Unfortunately users will have to call the magic file /etc/magic.mime.mime in this case.
```

Comment: finfo::finfo() [<a href='finfo.finfo'>finfo.finfo</a>]: Failed to load magic database at ''. This is what I get.

I tried to copy the magic file to etc/ as well but to no avail

Comment: What server distribution and version are you using ?