# Problems with thumbnail showing

Tags: php, wordpress, thumbnails

Thumbnails not showing on my (freshblog theme) home and archive page, here http://goo.gl/EY5ljA

It seems error is here:

```
Warning: finfo_open() [function.finfo-open]: Failed to load magic database at '/usr/share/misc/magic'. in /home/eedcorgge/domains/eedc.org.ge/public_html/wp-content/themes/freshblog/includes/timthumb.php on line 373
```

http://eedc.org.ge/wp-content/themes/freshblog/includes/timthumb.php?src=http://eedc.org.ge/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/10434345_315215635301355_8010689018037474726_n.jpg&h=100&w=100&zc=1

I tried to use new version of timthumb.php, tried to change cache and other folders permission, but no results.

I found similar problem here [Failed to load magic database at '' Laravel 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17045340/failed-to-load-magic-database-at-laravel-4)

But Don,t know what to do.
Can anyone help me with fresh idea?

Comment: Kindly Refer this link:- http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.finfo-open.php

Comment: Warning

The expected magic database format changed in PHP 5.3.11 and 5.4.1. Due to this, the internal magic database was upgraded. This mostly effects code where an external magic database is used: reading an older magic file will now fail. Also, some textual representations of the mime types has changed, for instance for PHP would be "PHP script, ASCII text" instead of "PHP script text" returned.

Comment: Note:

    Generally, using the bundled magic database (by leaving magic_file and the MAGIC environment variables unset) is the best course of action unless you specifically need a custom magic database.

Comment: Depends on what are you trying to achieve...

Comment: I trying to see thumbnails on home and archive page :)

Comment: Than what don't you just display thumbnail using `get_thumbnail` ?